# Ionic 4 splash screen not hiding in production mode

Tags: cordova-plugins, splash-screen, ionic4

I have build an app everything is working perfectly. When i run the app through

```
ionic cordova run android
```

But which i run the app in production mode splash screen is not hiding. Alert is also not showing up on `platform.ready()`

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

here is **config.xml**

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
     private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
     private statusBar: StatusBar
   ) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      alert('YES');              //this also not showing in production mode
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors you see?

Comment: It show this  `StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at t.CcnG.t.get `  in chrome inspect tool but only the error is in release build.

Comment: We are also getting the same behaviour — do you find this happens when you run with both —prod on its own as well as when running with —prod —release? Are you by any chance using a custom splash screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry! I had installed a native plugin `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` and I did not added it to the `provider` array in `app.module.ts`.

After adding it the native plugin to `app.module.ts` everything was perfect.

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [               // Add Native plugins in this array
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    SocialSharing, 
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```